# Multiselect a optgroup and show corresponding count fields?

Tags: jquery, multi-select, optgroup

i am using jquery +bootstrap+bootstrapselect  to develop a form. But now i am stuck. I would like to  display a count field foreach selection. For example, if mustard, relish and steamed are selected i would like to show 3 count inputfields with corresponding names and store the combo in mysql.

I am trying out jquery-interdependencies but haven't got it to work.

Here's the optgroup

```
 <select id="food" name="food[]" class="selectpicker" multiple>
    <optgroup label="Condiments">
      <option>Mustard</option>
      <option>Ketchup</option>
      <option>Relish</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Breads">
      <option>Plain</option>
      <option>Steamed</option>
      <option>Toasted</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
```

and the jquery-interdepencies part (which only works for one selection)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            // Start creating a new ruleset
            var ruleset = $.deps.createRuleset();

            // Show 
            var foodRuleMustard = ruleset.createRule("#food", "==", "mustard");
            foodRuleMustard.include("#num_of_mustard");
            var foodRuleKetchup = ruleset.createRule("#food", "==", "ketchup");
            foodRuleKetchup.include("#num_of_ketchup");
            var foodRuleRelish = ruleset.createRule("#food", "==", "relish");
            foodRuleRelish.include("#num_of_relish");
            //etc

            // Make the ruleset effective on the whole page
            ruleset.install({log: true});
        });
```

tried to make a jsfiddle but that didn't work either: http://jsfiddle.net/9p062q9m/

Comment: i am trying this approach but i can't get it to hide
 $(document).ready(function() {
                
`                  $("#food").change(function () {
                      $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
                        
                        $('#num_of_'+$(this).attr("value")).show();
                        console.log("Selection: "+$(this).attr("value"));
                    });
                  });`

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have ditch the jquery-interdepencies and just added a class="colors" to the num_of input fields and
before the each loop hide the class="colors" input fields

```
`       $(document).ready(function() {

                  $("#food").change(function () {
                       $('.foods').hide();
                      $("#food option:selected").each(function(){
                          var str = $(this).attr("value");
                            $('#num_of_'+str).show();
                    });
                  });

            });`
```